# How could i add all xml element names (distinct) to a dictionary with xml.etree.cElementTree.iterparse

Tags: celementtree

```
def count_tags(osm_file):
    found = {}
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(osm_file):
```

Id like to get with xml.etree.**c**ElementTree.iterparse form a huge file the xml root and the top level tags and add them disticnt to a dict. May there someone could help me please.